# Chart Is Not Created

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I am using this syntax to attempt to create a donut graph on my page.  Console shows no errors, but I have no graph created.

I have verified that the query is accurate and valid.  I have also verified using console.log that the JavaScript array is being populated with the results as expected.

Something is preventing the chart from displaying but console is empty.
What should I change in order for the graph to display on the page as I need?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("site", "user", "pass", "db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="Select donorName, numdonors500Club, numdonors5000Club, numdonors50000Club, numdonors500000Club, numdonors500000000Club FROM donors";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$data = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);

?>

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="doughnut-chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ctx = document.getElementById('doughnut-chart').getContext('2d');
var information = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut-chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["500 Club", "5000 Club", "50000 Club", "500000 Club", "5000000 Club"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Donors",
          data: information, 
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Donor Info'
      }
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` you supply in

```
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Donors",
      data: information, 
    }
  ]
```

ie. `information` is a `number[]`, an array of numbers. Your SQL query returns a `JSON` object. So you will need to include only the numerical values from individual objects. You can use `.map()` for this. Include all the fields except the `donorName`

Comment: Can I modify the query to not return donorName, then I'm only returning the number[] array and it will map properly?

Comment: Yes if `donorName` is not required elsewhere. Also use `MYSQLI_ARRAY` instead, then you will not need `map()`

Comment: MYSQLI_Array instead of MYSQLI_ASSOC?  Awesome, let me check out your suggestions after removing the varchar field

Comment: Actually `MYSQLI_ARRAY ` would still convert to an object with `json_encode`, just with keys being `0`, `1`, etc instead of `numdonors500Club`, `numdonors5000Club`, etc. So you can create an array using keys directly.

Comment: I changed it to MYSQLI_ARRAY and removed the varchar field but no chart is still being displayed onscreen and console is error free